How to use @OptIn annotion in kotlin notebook with file scope
I want to apply the @OptIn annotation to whole kotlin notebook with @file scope and not for each individual cell. I see other annotations @file:DependOn and @file:Repository, are suppported and work across whole notebook, but not OptIn.
How can I make this work? I am using Kotlin Notebook inside IntelliJ Ultimate. But it might be same with Jupytor notebook as well.
It works fine for individual variable, function or cell.
Ex. for single variable,
@OptIn(kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi::class)
var abc = Path(".").walk()

or for multiple variables within a single cell,
@file:OptIn(kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi::class)

var abc = Path(".").walk()
var def = Path(".").walk()

